# Converting over asp functions to php

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am attempting to translate or convert these functions from a .asp file into .php functions as i am not familiar with .asp as of yet.
Some of them i recognize and can comprehend such as the SQL commands and the placeholders where data from the remote table would go, and the rest have my confused.
I have already converted some such as the include which i believe is the equivalent to PHP's include ''; function and several others. Could someone with working knowledge of both languages show me which functions go where?

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/functions.asp" -->
<%
intBusiness_Catagory = Request("select_catagory")

Set thisConn    = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
thisConn.Open CreateAfccDSN()


SelectSQL   = "SELECT * FROM BusinessInfo WHERE ((CatID = " & intBusiness_Catagory & ") or (CatID2 = " & intBusiness_Catagory & ") or (CatID3 = " & intBusiness_Catagory & ")) and (intStatusCodeID = 1) and (intOnWeb = 1) Order By vcBusinessName"
Set SelectRs = thisConn.Execute(SelectSQL)

If SelectRs.EOF Then
    Response.Write("No members found for selected category.<br> Please search <a href='javascript:history.back()'>again</a>.")
Else
%>
<b>Member Search Results:</b>
<p>

<%
End If

    If Not SelectRs.BOF AND Not SelectRs.EOF then
        SelectRs.MoveFirst
        Do Until SelectRs.EOF
%>
            <b><%=SelectRs("vcBusinessName") %></b><br>
            <%=SelectRs("vcPhone") %><br>
            <%=SelectRs("vcPAddress") %><br>
            <%=SelectRs("vcPCity") %>, <%=SelectRs("vcPState") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=SelectRs("vcPZipCode") %><br>
            <%
            If isNull(SelectRs("vcURL")) then

            Else
            %>
                <b>Website: </b><a href="http://<%=SelectRs("vcURL") %>" target="_blank"><%=SelectRs("vcURL") %></a>
            <%
            End If
            %>
            <p>
            <hr>
<%
            SelectRs.MoveNext
        Loop
%>

<%
    End If

SelectRs.Close
Set SelectRs = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: No one is going to re-write your code for you. Which parts of the ASP code don't you understand?

Comment: The if statements, the Rewrite statements, the Set thisConn    = Server.CreateObject, thisConn.Open CreateAfccDSN() and the intBusiness_Catagory mainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script opens a database, makes a query and spits out values from the resulting records. Not everything here has a 1:1 PHP equivalent.

`Set thisConn = Server.CreateObject` - this creates a database connection object

`thisConn.Open CreateAfccDSN()` - This opens the database connection, using values passed back from a function called CreateAfccDSN(), which is not shown here.

`intBusiness_Catagory = Request("select_catagory")` - This takes a form/url parameter called `select_catagory` and assigns it to the local variable `intBusiness_Catagory`

Comment: ok thanks! This should help me out. What about the rewrite command?

Comment: Ok i see. Though in the code there is no sign of database user and passwords or even a login procedure. Not to sure how good this will work with PHP.

Comment: CreateAfccDSN() will tell you where the database is and if a login is required. Sometimes it just points to a file if they're using MS access DB